# adding swipe inside onBindViewHolder RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

hey guys Im trying to use swipe inside onBindViewHolder because my items are from the database but I think it doesnt seem to work cuz my app is crashing. Im using this custom cursor adapter for my recyclerview https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59  here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
        mItems = cursor;
        final int     id      = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ID));
        final String  title   = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_TITLE_REMINDER));
        final String  desc    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_DESC_REMINDER));
        final String  date    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_DATE_REMINDER));

        viewHolder.title.setText(title);

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
                int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                notifyItemRemoved(itemPosition);
                dbHandler.deleteReminder(id);
            }
        };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(this.myRecyclerview);
}
```

Is there anyway I can do swiping to dismiss my items in recyclerview?

Comment: post your logcat please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following chunk of code from onBindViewHolder and add in your activity or fragment from where you are initializing adapter.

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {     // type cast your view holder
                // CusrsorViewHolder cViewHolder = (CursorViewHolder)viewHolder;
                int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                notifyItemRemoved(itemPosition);
                dbHandler.deleteReminder(cViewHolder.id);
            }
        };

 ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
 itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(this.myRecyclerview);
 //put the above code before the following method in your activity or fragment
 //this.RecylerView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Set your id in onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
        mItems = cursor;
        final int     id      = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ID));
        viewHolder.id = id;
}
```

Comment: but how will I be able to get the Id? thanks for replying BTW

Comment: @alvinvaldez i have edited my answer please check and let me know if it helped you

Comment: it says cannot resolve symbole 'id' heres my code in pastie: http://pastie.org/10519420

Comment: ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder)viewHolder; 
int itemPosition = itemViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(itemPosition);
                dbHandler.deleteReminder(itemViewHolder.id);
@alvinvaldez put this code in your onSwipe

Comment: ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder)viewHolder is in red color I think it is not recognize inside MainActivity

Comment: @alvinvaldez Make your ItemViewHolder Class public and import it in your main activity

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to delete the item from the list. orderlist is the RecyclerView variable.

```
SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener touchListener =
    new SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener(
            orderlist,
            new SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                        /*db.deleteOrderProduct(ordereditems.get(position).getOrder_pro_Code());
                        if(position>1){
                            listposition = position-1;
                        }*/
                        //ordereditems.remove(position);
                        //adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //displayOrderList();
                        DeleteOrderById(position);

                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
orderlist.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Waleed Sarwar for helping me solve it.

I was using https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59 for my recyclerviewcursoradapter.

MainActivity.java

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            RemindersAdapter.ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (RemindersAdapter.ItemViewHolder)viewHolder;
            int itemPosition = itemViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(itemPosition);
            // get the id of an item via itemViewHolder.id
            dbHandler.deleteReminder(itemViewHolder.id);

            // update cursor upon deleting do avoid
            // the card from coming back upon swipe
            adapter.swapCursor(dbHandler.getAllReminders());
        }
    };

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(listReminder);
```

RemindersAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
    final int     id      = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ID));
    final String  title   = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_TITLE_REMINDER));
    final String  desc    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_DESC_REMINDER));
    final String  date    = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDBHandler.COLUMN_DATE_REMINDER));

    viewHolder.title.setText(title);

    // pass id to viewholder to get in swipe
    viewHolder.id = id;
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public int id;
    TextView title;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reminderTitle);
        }
}
```

Im using  adapter.swapCursor(dbHandler.getAllReminders()); from my adapter which was a method from abstract class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter that makes the cursor updated upon deleting because without it, the deleted item will be recreated by onBindViewHolder.